# Dask read_csv: skip periodically ocurring lines

Tags: python, dask

I want to use Dask to read in a large file of atom coordinates at multiple time steps. The format is called XYZ file, and it looks like this:

`3
timestep 1
  C         9.5464696279        5.2523477968        4.4976072664
  C        10.6455075132        6.0351186102        4.0196547961
  C        10.2970471574        7.3880736108        3.6390228968
     3
timestep 2
  C         9.5464696279        5.2523477968        4.4976072664
  C        10.6455075132        6.0351186102        4.0196547961
  C        10.2970471574        7.3880736108        3.6390228968`

The first line contains the atom number, the second line is just a comment.
After that, the atoms are listed with their names and positions.
After all atoms are listed, the same is repeated for the next time step.

I would now like to load such a trajectory via `dask.dataframe.read_csv`.
However, I could not figure out how to skip the periodically ocurring lines containing the atom number and the comment. Is this actually possible?

**Edit**:

Reading this format into a Pandas Dataframe is possible via:

```
atom_nr = 3

def skip(line_nr):
    return line_nr % (atom_nr + 2) < 2


pd.read_csv(xyz_filename, skiprows=skip, delim_whitespace=True,
            header=None)
```

But it looks like the Dask dataframe does not support to pass a function to skiprows.

**Edit 2**:
MRocklin's answer works! Just for completeness, I write down the full code I used.

```
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
import dask.bytes
import dask.dataframe
import dask.delayed


atom_nr = ...
filename = ...


def skip(line_nr):
    return line_nr % (atom_nr + 2) < 2


def pandaread(data_in_bytes):
    pseudo_file = BytesIO(data_in_bytes[0])
    return pd.read_csv(pseudo_file, skiprows=skip, delim_whitespace=True,
                       header=None)

bts = dask.bytes.read_bytes(filename, delimiter=f"{atom_nr}\ntimestep".encode())
dfs = dask.delayed(pandaread)(bts)

sol = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(dfs)
sol.compute()
```

The only remaining question is: How do I tell dask to only compute the first n frames? At the moment it seems the full trajectory is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

No, neither pandas.read_csv nor dask.dataframe.read_csv offer this kind of functionality (to my knowledge)

#### Long Answer

If you can write code to convert some of this data into a pandas dataframe, then you can probably do this on your own with moderate effort using

- [dask.bytes.read_bytes](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bytes.html?highlight=read_bytes#dask.bytes.read_bytes)
- [dask.dataframe.from_delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html)

In general this might look something like the following:

```
values = read_bytes('filenames.*.txt', delimiter='...', blocksize=2**27)
dfs = [dask.delayed(load_pandas_from_bytes)(v) for v in values]
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

Each of the dfs correspond to roughly `blocksize` bytes of your data (and then up until the next delimiter).  You can control how fine you want your partitions to be using this blocksize.  If you want you can also select only a few of these `dfs` objects to get a smaller portion of your data

```
dfs = dfs[:5]  # only the first five blocks of `blocksize` data
```

Comment: I have one follow-up question: is it possible to restrict the number of dataframes read? When I try the code above (see **Edit 2**), dask will always try to read the complete file.